# Can someone explain how this javascript closure works?

Tags: javascript, closures

Ok,  I am staring to learn how closures work......and I have been stuck on this one for a few hours.  I just don't understand how it works.

I have to find the final value for the variable ***result***.

```
    var hidden = mystery(3);
    var jumble = mystery3(hidden);
    var result = jumble(2);

    function mystery ( input ){
      var secret = 4;
      input+=2;
      function mystery2 ( multiplier ) { 
         multiplier *= input;
         return secret * multiplier;
      }
      return mystery2;
    }


    function mystery3 ( param ){
      function mystery4 ( bonus ){
        return param(6) + bonus;
      }
      return mystery4;
    }
```

The answer is 122, but I am not sure how that number.

The answer that I calculated is is 362.  That was obviously wrong.

I got 362 like this

```
var hidden = mystery(3);
var jumble = mystery3(hidden);
var result = jumble(2);

function mystery ( input ){  //used 3 as an input
  var secret = 4;
  input+=2;
  function mystery2 ( multiplier ) { //used 3 as multiplier
     multiplier *= input; // 3 * 5
     return secret * multiplier;
  }
  return mystery2;   //returned 60
}


function mystery3 ( param ){  //used 60 as param
  function mystery4 ( bonus ){ //used 2 as bonus
    return param(6) + bonus; //60(6) + 2
  }
  return mystery4; // answer is 362
}
```

Can someone tell me how exactly you can get the answer 122?

Comment: I typed results; into my console, and got back 122....it's a confusing one for sure..

Comment: Why don't you explain how you got to 362.

Comment: Ok...I just added how I got to 362

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, closure means that a value of a local variable that has gone out of scope is retained inside a function.

Let's look at your code step by step:

```
var hidden = mystery(3);
```

Now, `mystery` returns a function. But what does it actually return. A simple `alert(hidden)` statement will tell you that it returns,

```
function mystery2( multiplier ) {
    multiplier *= input;
    return secret * multiplier;
}
```

Now if you look at the values of the local variables of this function,

- `multiplier` is an argument, it's value will be whatever that is passed to it when it is called
- But what is the value of `input`?
- And of `secret`?

This is where closures come into play. The value of input will be taken from the scope that this function was created on. What was the values for `input` and `secret` when this function was created? Let's take a look at `mystery` again:

```
function mystery ( input ){ // value 3 is passed here as a parameter
    var secret = 4;
    input+=2;
    ...
}
```

So we find that `input` was in fact had the value `5`, and `secret` had the value `4`. Now the returned function essentially becomes equivalent to:

```
function mystery2( multiplier ) {
    multiplier *= 5;
    return 4 * multiplier;
    // for future use, let's say that above statement is equivalent to:
    // return 4 * (multiplier * 5);                               ----- (1)
    // (now be a good boy/girl and don't scroll down to end)
}
```

OK, next:

```
var jumble = mystery3(hidden);
```

Again, `mystery3` returns a function. `alert(jumble)` gives us this:

```
function mystery4( bonus ){
    return param(6) + bonus;
}
```

Again, thinking in the same way as before we can say that this is equivalent to:

```
function mystery4( bonus ){
    return mystery2(6) + bonus; // param <- hidden <- mistery2
} //                                                             ----- (2)
```

And lastly,

```
var result = jumble(2);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var result = mystery4(2);
```

That is,

```
var result = mystery2(6) + 2; // because (2), see above
```

Which is,

```
var result = 4 * (6 * 5) + 2; // because (1), see above
```

Phew...

```
122
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed some names around to make it more readable for me, add a few comments to point out values at the time of the line's execution.

```
var mystery2_handle = mystery(3);
var mystery4_handle = mystery3(mystery2_handle);
var result = mystery4_handle(2);

function mystery ( input ){
    var secret = 4;
    input+=2; //5
    function mystery2 ( multiplier ) { 
        multiplier *= input; //6*5
        return secret * multiplier; //30*4
    }
    return mystery2;
}


function mystery3 ( _mystery2_handle ){
    function mystery4 ( bonus ){ //2
        return _mystery2_handle(6) + bonus; //120+2
    }
    return mystery4;
}
```

Let's go step by step:

1. mystery(3) -> input will be set to 5
2. then return mystery2 function handle
3. pass that handle to mystery3
4. which returns mystery4 handle inside of which the mystery2 handle is accessed
5. execute mystery4 with bonus parameter set to 2
6. execute mystery2 with multiplier parameter set to 6
7. in which multiplies it by 5 = 30
8. then multiply secret 4 by 30 = 120
9. return the 120 to which 2 (bonus) is added in mystery 4
10. Voila 122

http://jsfiddle.net/3F4pz/ Run the code insert alerts where needed to check data.
Just remember that even though the code is top down does not mean it's executed that way. And I'm not sure how you came up with 362.

Comment: Thank You.  ok....this is good....let me try and digest...i might have some more questions

Comment: just edited the step description a bit, multiplier is 6 because it's passed 6 down on the bottom in mystery4

Comment: @user3843070 i think you need to understand that when passing functions around they are not executed when they are passed or returned but rather when they are called?
for example when you say `return mystery2; //returned 60` it does not return 60 it actually returns the function **to be** executed. In this case executed way down in mystery4.

Comment: Yes...why is multiplier 6?

Comment: multiplier is 6 on step 6.
multiplier is a parameter that is passed the value of 6 in function mystery4, that is also when the code of mystery2 is being executed. The code of mystery2 in mystery is only a declaration it's not being executed in that instance. I'm sorry that I cannot clarify myself more thoroughly

Comment: thanks ff.....no need to apologize.  this closure thing is tricky....i'm just trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @user3843070: Closures are not that tricky. Forget the too complex sounding name _closure_. It's just a method of retaining values of local variables after the scope of that local variables has been ended. See my answer below. You may be able to "wrap your head around it".